# Does the potential of a charged ring diverge on the ring?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, singularities

I know that the density and potential (in spherycals) of a charged ring is, respectively,:

$$
\rho(\textbf{r})
=
\frac{\lambda}{a}
\delta(r-a)\delta(\theta-\tfrac{\pi}{2})
$$

$$
\varphi(\textbf{r})=
\frac{2\pi a \lambda}{r_>}
\left[
 1+    \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\left(\frac{r_<}{r_>}\right)^{2n}P_{2n}(\cos\theta)
\right]
$$

Where $P_{2n}$ is the $2n$-th Legendre Polynomial, and $r_<=\min\{a,r\},r_>=\max\{a,r\}$. If I evaluate $\mathbf r$ in the ring ($r=a,\theta=\tfrac{\pi}{2}$):

$$
\varphi(\mathbf r)\,\propto\,
\left[
1+    \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}
\right]
\to\infty
$$

So this is a problem (I suppose).

Comment: Actually, I'm rethinking my answer. Are you sure that your sum for the energy does not also have a term like $P_{2n}(0)$? My answer was assuming that the sum was as you stated, but in trying to derive your result, I seem to have gotten something different.

Comment: @Philip Thank you so much for your answer, you have a [recurrence relation for the Polynomials Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Recurrence_relations) $(n+1)P_{n+1}=(2n+1)xP_n(x) - nP_{n-1}(x)$, and $P_0(0)=1,\quad P_1(0)=0$, so you can say $P_{2n}(0)=(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$ and $P_{2n+1}(0)=0$ for $n>0$

Comment: Oh great! I never paid as much attention as I should have to recurrence relations. But in that case, would the formula for the potential $\varphi(\mathbf{r})$ *also* have the same double factorial terms in it? I'm afraid that given your formula for $\varphi$, I can't derive your formula for $U_E$. It might be a typo? Also, does my answer answer your question? :)

Comment: It is the [continous form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy#Energy_stored_in_electronic_elements) of [the energy for discrete charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy#Electrostatic_potential_energy_stored_in_a_system_of_point_charges). You answer my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a fun question, I learnt something new about double factorials while trying to answer it!

I don't see why that term diverges. Using the [identities on Wikipedia for the "double factorial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Additional_identities), we have that for even integers $k$,

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{k}(x)\text{d}x = \frac{(k-1)!!}{(k)!!}\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

We can use this to calculate the sum term you have explicitly.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n}(x)\text{d}x = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \text{d}x \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sin^{2n}(x).$$

Where in the last step I've interchanged the sum and the integral. This particular sum is quite easy to do, and I'll leave it as an exercise to show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sin^{2n}(x) = -\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}.$$

We can now perform the integral and show that $$-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)} \text{d}x = \frac{-2 + \sqrt{2}}{2}.$$

Thus, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{-2 + \sqrt{2}}{2} < \infty,$$

which should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works to me!!

Comment: I'm going to change the question, because I have an error.

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/558212/can-the-energy-of-a-charged-ring-have-some-sense) is the new question

Comment: @Elborito I think it might be better to just edit this question, perhaps? I think repeating questions is frowned up. Also, I am not sure how you got the $$\left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^2$$ term, since I only got one which came from the Legendre Polynomial recurrence relations. Perhaps you could edit the question with a little bit more of your working?