# Can the energy of a charged ring have some sense?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, potential

I know that the density and potential (in spherycals) of a charged ring is, respectively,:

$$
\rho(\textbf{r})
=
\frac{\lambda}{a}
\delta(r-a)\delta(\theta-\tfrac{\pi}{2})
$$

$$
\varphi(\textbf{r})=
\frac{2\pi a \lambda}{r_>}
\left[
 1+    \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\left(\frac{r_<}{r_>}\right)^{2n}P_{2n}(\cos\theta)
\right]
$$

Where $P_{2n}$ is the $2n$-th Legendre Polynomial, and $r_<=\min\{a,r\},r_>=\max\{a,r\}$. If I use the following formula of the electrostatic energy:

$$
U_E=\frac12\int\rho(\textbf r)\varphi(\textbf r)d^3\textbf{r}
\,\propto\,
\left[
1+    \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^2
\right]
\to\infty
$$

So this is a problem, because this is not useful. I don't know if in this case the following affirmation is right:
$$
U_E=\frac12\int\rho(\textbf r)\varphi(\textbf r)d^3\textbf{r}
\stackrel{?}{=}
\frac{1}{8\pi}
\int |E|^2
d^3\textbf{r}
$$

In case of they aren't the same, can I associate this to the potential energy?

Comment: You have a multipole expansion of the potential, but you're assuming all of the multipole moments are equal. Is this a correct assumption? Or should you have some coefficient $c_n$ on each term?

Comment: Why are you saying that the multipole moments are equal? I don't understand sorry.

Comment: The expression for $\varphi$ looks like a multipole expansion. Is it not?

Comment: @probably_someone I don't know if it's the same what i do, I wrote the [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Statement_of_the_equation) like [Legendre Polynomials expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) $\dfrac{1}{|\mathbf x - \mathbf x'|}=  \dfrac{1}{r_>}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \left(\dfrac{r_<}{r_>}\right)^nP_n(\cos\gamma)$